# How to call dynamically @BeforeClass,@BeforeTest or @BeforeMethod in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

My Code looks Like below

```
public class SeleniumBase {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SeleniumBase.class);      
    protected WebDriver driver = null;
    protected String browserType = null;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters(value = "browser")
    public final void initializeBeforeClass(String driverType) throws IOException {
        browserType = driverType;
        BrowserType browserTypeEnum = BrowserType.valueOf(driverType);
        driver = SeleniumDriverManager.getWebDriver(browserTypeEnum);
    }

    @AfterTest(alwaysRun=true)
    public final void destroy() {
        logger.info("After Suite Run, going to close the open browser "+browserType);
        if (driver != null) {
            SeleniumDriverManager.quitWebDriver(driver, browserType);
        }else{
            logger.warn("Driver instance not available for close in the destroy method for "+browserType);
        }
    }
}
```

My SeleniumDriverManager is holding the ThreadLocal. ThreafLocal is  necessary because Selenium WebDriver is not Thread Safe.

So If we not used ThreadLocal then when we try to close the driver it could not close the correct one So my SeleniumDriverManager class looks like below:

```
public class SeleniumDriverManager {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SeleniumDriverManager.class);
    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> threadWebDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public static WebDriver getWebDriver(BrowserType browserTypeEnum) throws IOException {
        WebDriver currentDriver = threadWebDriver.get();

        if (currentDriver == null)
        {
            boolean remoteDriver = TestSetUp.isRemoteTestRun();

            if(remoteDriver){
                logger.debug("Creating remote web driver instance for "+browserTypeEnum);
                try {
                    currentDriver = SeleniumRemoteWebDriverFactory.getWebDriver(browserTypeEnum);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error occured while instantiating remote web driver for "+browserTypeEnum,e);
                }
            }else{
                logger.debug("Creating local web driver instance for "+browserTypeEnum);
                currentDriver = SeleniumLocalWebDriverFactory.getWebDriver(browserTypeEnum);
            }
            threadWebDriver.set(currentDriver);
        }
        return threadWebDriver.get();
    }

    public static void quitWebDriver(WebDriver driver, String browserType) {
        WebDriver currentDriver = threadWebDriver.get();
        if (currentDriver != null) {
            currentDriver.quit();
            threadWebDriver.set(null);
        }
    }
}
```

So now problem is If I try to run my test in parallel with respect to Methods then I need to use @BeforeMethod in the place of @BeforeTest or If I want my test will run in parallel of Class then I need to use @BeforeClass.

So how can I overcome this problem that if I need to change

`<suite name="Suite" parallel="class"> or <suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">` I don't need to change my SeleniumBase class annotation. Here I am using TestNG.

**UPDATE**

New Selenium Base Class

```
public class SeleniumBase {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SeleniumBase.class);

    protected WebDriver driver = null;

    protected String browserType = null;

    @BeforeSuite
    @Parameters(value = "browser")
    public final void initializeBeforeSuite(String driverType, ITestContext iTestCtx) throws IOException {
        if (iTestCtx.getSuite().getParallel().equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            browserType = driverType;
            BrowserType browserTypeEnum = BrowserType.valueOf(driverType);
            driver = SeleniumDriverManager.getWebDriver(browserTypeEnum);
            System.out.println("BeforeSuite End");
        }
    }

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters(value = "browser")
    public final void initializeBeforeTest(String driverType, ITestContext iTestCtx) throws IOException {
        if (iTestCtx.getSuite().getParallel().equalsIgnoreCase("tests")) {
            logger.info("BeforeTest Called");
            browserType = driverType;
            BrowserType browserTypeEnum = BrowserType.valueOf(driverType);
            driver = SeleniumDriverManager.getWebDriver(browserTypeEnum);
        }
    }

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters(value = "browser")
    public final void initializeBeforeClass(String driverType, ITestContext iTestCtx) throws IOException {
        if (iTestCtx.getSuite().getParallel().equalsIgnoreCase("classes")) {
            logger.info("BeforeClass Called");
            browserType = driverType;
            BrowserType browserTypeEnum = BrowserType.valueOf(driverType);
            driver = SeleniumDriverManager.getWebDriver(browserTypeEnum);
        }
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters(value = "browser")
    public final void initializeBeforeMethod(String driverType, ITestContext iTestCtx) throws IOException {
        if (iTestCtx.getSuite().getParallel().equalsIgnoreCase("methods")) {
            logger.info("BeforeMethod Called");
            browserType = driverType;
            BrowserType browserTypeEnum = BrowserType.valueOf(driverType);
            driver = SeleniumDriverManager.getWebDriver(browserTypeEnum);
        }
    }


    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public final void destroySuiteLevelBrowser(ITestContext iTestCtx) {
        if (iTestCtx.getSuite().getParallel().equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            logger.info("After Suite Run, going to close the open browser " + browserType);
            if (driver != null) {
                SeleniumDriverManager.quitWebDriver(driver, browserType);
            } else {
                logger.warn("Driver instance not available for close in the destroy method for " + browserType);
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public final void destroyTestLevelBrowser(ITestContext iTestCtx) {
        if (iTestCtx.getSuite().getParallel().equalsIgnoreCase("tests")) {
            logger.info("After Test Run, going to close the open browser " + browserType);
            if (driver != null) {
                SeleniumDriverManager.quitWebDriver(driver, browserType);
            } else {
                logger.warn("Driver instance not available for close in the destroy method for " + browserType);
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public final void destroyClassLevelBrowser(ITestContext iTestCtx) {
        if (iTestCtx.getSuite().getParallel().equalsIgnoreCase("classes")) {
            logger.info("After Class Run, going to close the open browser " + browserType);
            if (driver != null) {
                SeleniumDriverManager.quitWebDriver(driver, browserType);
            } else {
                logger.warn("Driver instance not available for close in the destroy method for " + browserType);
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public final void destroyMethodLevelBrowser(ITestContext iTestCtx) {
        if (iTestCtx.getSuite().getParallel().equalsIgnoreCase("methods")) {
            logger.info("After Method Run, going to close the open browser " + browserType);
            if (driver != null) {
                SeleniumDriverManager.quitWebDriver(driver, browserType);
            } else {
                logger.warn("Driver instance not available for close in the destroy method for " + browserType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Test Class Looks Like

```
public class PageObjectTest extends SeleniumBase {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PageObjectTest.class);

    /**
     * This Is Created To Go the Base Page Before Every Test
     */

    @BeforeMethod
    public void testMethodSetUp() {
        logger.info("BeforeMethod Called For Default Page Load");
        driver.get("http://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.in/2013/12/frmset1.html");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSubmit() throws Exception {
        logger.info("---------------testSubmit Start---------------");
/*      BlogTestPage blog = new BlogTestPage(driver);
        blog.submitForm("Test");*/
        logger.info("---------------testSubmit Complete---------------");
    }

    @Test(dataProviderClass = DataClass.class, dataProvider = "google-search-text")
    public void testGoogleLink(String searchTxt) throws Exception {
        logger.info("---------------testGoogleLink Start With "+searchTxt+"---------------");
//      BlogTestPage blog = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BlogTestPage.class);
        /*BlogTestPage blog = new BlogTestPage(driver);
        blog.clickonGoogleLink().searchTxt(searchTxt);
        Assert.assertEquals(searchTxt, new GoogleHomePage(driver).getSearchTxt());*/
        logger.info("---------------testGoogleLink Complete With "+searchTxt+"---------------");
    }

}
```

Now I observe that when It call driver.get() from TestClass @BeforeMethod It aging call @BeforeTest,@BeforeTest and @BeforeMethod of SeleniumBase class and Test stop abruptly after executing one  from TestNG XML. How I can get rid from this issue.

Comment: won't `@BeforeMethod` give you the desired behaviour in both cases `...parallel="class" ...` or `...parallel="methods"...` ?

Comment: No it is not giving me the desired behavior because think user give paralle ="false" then it will close and open browser for each method but as per need it should be open or close after suite complete.

Comment: see http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection

you could add an argument of type ITestContext to an annotated method and get the parallel string value and take action accordingly 
`
    @BeforeMethod
    public void before(ITestContext iTestContext){
        ....
        final String parallel = iTestContext.getSuite().getParallel();
        ....
    }
`

Comment: Although the way you are doing it works, if you call WebDriverManager.getWebDriver from within a Dataprovider, then you can feed the driver into the each test method via a constructor arg and let TestNG worry about threading instead of using ThreadLocal.   Your test would not ITSELF need to call a thread-safe drivermanager, but instead it could call a simple Builder class.  Just a thought.

Comment: @diarmudid I implemented this as per your suggestion Like@BeforeSuite
 @Parameters(value = "browser")
 public final void initializeBeforeSuite(String driverType, ITestContext iTestCtx) throws IOException {
  if (iTestCtx.getSuite().getParallel().equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {.....}

Comment: @diarmudid I implemented this as per your suggestion Like BeforeSuite  Parameters(value = "browser") public final void initializeBeforeSuite(String driverType, ITestContext iTestCtx) throws IOException { if (iTestCtx.getSuite().getParallel().equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {.....} and also for  BeforeTest, BeforeClass, BeforeMethod. But I face new problem when I call  BeforeMethod from TestClass to load base URL for each test method then It agin call  BeforeTest, BeforeClass, BeforeMethod from SeleniumBaseClass and after running One <test> from TestNG XML test stop abruptly. Updated Code above.